# Positoning div-containers

Tags: html, css, web, position

```css
.containerBigOverview{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 3%;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    background-color:red;
}
.containerOverview {
  position: relative;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .containerOverview {
      position: relative;
      width: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      margin: 3%;
      float: none;
    }
}
.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.containerOverview:hover .overlay {
  height: 50%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

/* FOOTER */

.footer {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    background-color: #aaa;
    color: white;
    padding: 2%;
}

.footer a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:white;
    padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
<div class="containerBigOverview">
    <div class="containerOverview">
      <img src="https://gradle.org/images/gradle-400x400.png" alt="Forbildung1" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerOverview">
      <img src="https://gradle.org/images/gradle-400x400.png" alt="Forbildung2" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="containerOverview">
      <img src="https://gradle.org/images/gradle-400x400.png" alt="Forbildung3" class="image">
      <div class="overlay">
        <div class="text">Hello World 3</div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
    

<div class="footer">
    <a href="impressum.html"> Impressum </a>
    <a href="datenschutz.html"> Datenschutz </a>
</div>
```

I am trying to make a website.
A problem came up:
I have got a div for a footer, and a div which is a container for several divs including an image.
Now the Footer is displayed over my Image-Container, and I have no clue why. [image] If I delete the position: relatives, my footer contains the image-container. [image]

Comment: Please create a codepen. Also, the footer is going on top of the images, because it has `position: absolute`. As the `footer` is after `containerBigOverview` in the HTML, it goes on top of it.

Comment: Sorry I am new - didn't know about codepen: https://codepen.io/LeoGries/pen/xxVOXEo - unfortunatly I dont know how to include images, so the effect is not good to see.
If I delete the position: absolute , the containerBigOverview is inside the footer.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I've found is to turn all your containers into flexboxes using `display: flex`. Flexboxes are much clearer than block displays - try it out.
Also, there is a special tag for footer in HTML `<footer>` so you don't need to create a new class.
Here's the fixed code: https://codepen.io/wiszuc/pen/RwaRLQK

Comment: Thank you! That helped!

Comment: Nice effort. Unfortunately, the hover animation does not seem to be working properly.

Comment: Yeah I recognized that later too :/ 
Can please someone explain me again, why my div class="containerBigOverlay" becomes a part of the footer? I am kind of getting crazy over that.. https://codepen.io/LeoGries/pen/xxVOXEo

Answer (score 0):

If you removed `position: relative` from your footer then the position becomes `position: static` by default, that is the overlay effect you might be seeing in this case.

Depending on what you would want to achieve, you can use different [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position).

In general for footer you could use:

```
.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

in order to attach it to the bottom of the page.

---

**Full working example:**

```css
body {
  min-height: 20rem;
}
.containerBigOverview{
  display: flex;
  postion: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  background-color:red;
}
.containerOverview {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  width: 31%;
  margin: 1%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .containerOverview {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 3%;
    float: none;
  }
}
.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgb(176, 224, 230, 0.9);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
}

.containerOverview:hover .overlay {
  height: 50%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

/* FOOTER */

.footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: white;
  padding: 2%;
}

.footer a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color:white;
  padding: 1%;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerBigOverview">
        <div class="containerOverview">
          <svg width="10em" height="1oem" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-alarm-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 0h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.002 7.002 0 0 1 3.537 12.26l.817.816a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-.924-.925A6.967 6.967 0 0 1 8 16a6.967 6.967 0 0 1-3.722-1.07l-.924.924a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l.817-.816A7.002 7.002 0 0 1 7 2.07V1H5.999a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM13.5 1c-.753 0-1.429.333-1.887.86a8.035 8.035 0 0 1 3.527 3.527A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 1zm-5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.882l-1.447 2.894a.5.5 0 1 0 .894.448l1.5-3A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5z"/>
</svg>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Hello World</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="containerOverview">
          <svg width="10em" height="1oem" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-alarm-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 0h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.002 7.002 0 0 1 3.537 12.26l.817.816a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-.924-.925A6.967 6.967 0 0 1 8 16a6.967 6.967 0 0 1-3.722-1.07l-.924.924a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l.817-.816A7.002 7.002 0 0 1 7 2.07V1H5.999a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM13.5 1c-.753 0-1.429.333-1.887.86a8.035 8.035 0 0 1 3.527 3.527A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 1zm-5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.882l-1.447 2.894a.5.5 0 1 0 .894.448l1.5-3A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5z"/>
</svg>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Hello World 2</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="containerOverview">
          <svg width="10em" height="1oem" viewBox="0 0 16 16" class="bi bi-alarm-fill" fill="currentColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.5.5A.5.5 0 0 1 6 0h4a.5.5 0 0 1 0 1H9v1.07a7.002 7.002 0 0 1 3.537 12.26l.817.816a.5.5 0 0 1-.708.708l-.924-.925A6.967 6.967 0 0 1 8 16a6.967 6.967 0 0 1-3.722-1.07l-.924.924a.5.5 0 0 1-.708-.708l.817-.816A7.002 7.002 0 0 1 7 2.07V1H5.999a.5.5 0 0 1-.5-.5zM.86 5.387A2.5 2.5 0 1 1 4.387 1.86 8.035 8.035 0 0 0 .86 5.387zM13.5 1c-.753 0-1.429.333-1.887.86a8.035 8.035 0 0 1 3.527 3.527A2.5 2.5 0 0 0 13.5 1zm-5 4a.5.5 0 0 0-1 0v3.882l-1.447 2.894a.5.5 0 1 0 .894.448l1.5-3A.5.5 0 0 0 8.5 9V5z"/>
</svg>
          <div class="overlay">
            <div class="text">Hello World 3</div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    
<div class="footer">
    <a href="impressum.html"> Impressum </a>
    <a href="datenschutz.html"> Datenschutz </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks you for answering!